# Python function keeps reiterating raw input question in command line

Tags: python, iteration, fibonacci, raw-input

I'm trying to write a Fibonacci sequence that can take a user's input as the multiplier for the generational increase in rabbits, i.e., 4 pairs of offspring produced for each pair of mature rabbits.

I have tried storing the integer form of the input in a new variable and moving around the position of when the raw input is asked:

```
def fibonacci(x):
    if x == 1:
        rabbit_pairs = 1
        return rabbit_pairs
    elif x == 2:
        rabbit_pairs = 1
        return rabbit_pairs
    elif x > 2:
        y = int(input("How many offspring per pair? ")) 
        rabbit_pairs = fibonacci(x-1) + (y * fibonacci(x-2))
        return rabbit_pairs
```

When I run my code, if x > 2, my input question is asked but it keeps getting asked instead of returning the corresponding number of rabbits. If x == 5, the command prompts for the number of rabbits per pair and then keeps asking for the number of rabbits per pair.

Comment: Just try to execute the given code in your mind you will know the exact problem. 

You are getting input in the function and calling the function again and again.

Comment: **y = int(input("How many offspring per pair? "))**  This line is executing with every function call. You need to replace it to the correct position

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are recursively calling the fibonacci for x > 2,
So when you pass x == 5, 
The function call are ,

> fibonacci(x-1) + (y * fibonacci(x-2))

```
fibonacci(4) + (5 * fibonacci(3))
In this case fibonacci(4) and fibonacci(3), x > 2
```

so the following statement will be executed until x <= 2

```
y = int(input("How many offspring per pair? "))
```

Ideally you should put this question outside the recursive function and pass the value in you fibonacci(x)